# ADAL.js - what is the IFrame target origin for embedding PowerBI dashboard

Tags: azure, iframe, powerbi, adal, adal.js

I'm using the [PowerBI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dashboards/get-dashboards-in-group) along with [ADAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) and getting Dashboards. I want to embed a Dashboard in an IFrame. I'm using Angular.JS
So what did was something like this. Notice I have used **"*"** as the IFrame Target Origin. `dashboardEmbedUrl` is obtained from the API call

```html
<iframe id="PBDashboard" ng-show="dashboardVisible" src="{{dashboardEmbededUrl}}" frameborder="0" style="height: 100vh; width: 100%"></iframe>
```

and in my controller

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("PBDashboard")
const loadIframeDashboardEventListner = function() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('adal.access.token.keyhttps://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api');
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
        action: "loadDashboard",
        accessToken: token
    }), "*") //target is *. what should be the specific URL needed here
}
```

and

```js
iframe.addEventListener("load",loadIframeDashboardEventListner);
```

This works perfectly fine but using **"*"** triggers a security warning in SonarCloud. It says to specify a target. I'm not sure what the target should be. The API call also gives a `webUrl` along with the `embedUrl`. I used the `webUrl` instead of the `"*"` and it rendered the IFrame data but also gave the following error in console
[image]